# Trying to write a mod_rewrite rule

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've changed my CMS and need to write a mod_rewrite rule to help redirect some of the old URLs.

What I'd like to do is:

1. remove "blog/archives"
2. replace underscores with dashes
3. replace ".html" with a trailing slash

The old link:

```
http://example.com/blog/archives/the_post_title.html
```

The new link

```
http://example.com/the-post-title/
```

To address 1 & 3 I thought something along the lines of this might work, but it's not.

```
RewriteRule ^/blog/archives/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?.html$ $1    [L]
```

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 1 and 3

```
RewriteRule ^/blog/archives/(.*?).html$ /$1/ [L,R=permanent]
```

(note that R=permanent use a 301 redirect, which will be cached for long time but does move your pagerank to the new URL. Use [L,R] to use normal redirection)

Comment: Thanks for the start. I ended up with: `RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*_.*) $1-$2 [N]   
 RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)$ /$1-$2        
 RewriteRule ^/blog/archives/(.*?).html$ /$1/ [L,R=301]     `